# Embed Video in Phonegap android application

Tags: android, html, cordova, html5-video

I want to have video playing in my index.html while developing phonegap android application.
But the HTML5 video is not working in webview of phonegap android application. Please suggest a way. I don't want a intent to fire a new activity and play the video in native android player instead i want it in same HtML page.

Answer (score 0):

It should just work normally. Things to check:

- Is the video-file hosted locally (not on an external server), external sources will be marked as unsafe.
- Is the path of your video file correct? Case sensitivity is important

Comment: video is hosted locally and path is also correct. Its just showing the controls but the video is not visible. I checked it in emulator and device as well.

Comment: nope it neither worked in emulator nor on the device. You can check by opening youtube in webview using phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar problems, and still haven't figured out how to get a locally stored video to play on newer Android platforms*, but I have found that embedding a remote video works pretty well.  This iframe worked on both the ios and android emulators.

```
<iframe width="240"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YE7VzlLtp-4" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

- there are a couple of plugins to play video for Android pre 4.x